# React Native Start failing to compile because of linter errors

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, react-native-web

I recently upgraded RN from version 0.59.4 to 0.61.5.

I want to use react-native-web and added react-scripts (3.4.1) and react-dom (16.13.1). After some cleaning up of native modules not supported, running `react-scripts start` results in failure to compile because of lint errors (no-undef, for example). These are not rules set up in my .eslintrc.js file and seem to come with the new way of running scripts.

Is there a way to ignore the lint errors to try and compile? While I could try and make these changes in my code base, there are some issues in dependencies as well.

Additionally, I updated my babel as per react-native-web

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "alias": {
        "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
      }
    }]
  ]
};
```

I have read this might be webpack related, but there is currently no webconfig. I tried adding what was on the react-native-web getting starter page, but had no luck there either.